# Update task status from external application in Databricks

Tags: databricks

I am having a workflow with a task that is dependant on external application execution (not residing in Databricks). After external application finishes, how to update the status of a task to complete. Currently, Jobs API doesn't support status updates.

Answer (score 0):

Runs Cancel is available

```
curl --netrc --request POST \
https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/jobs/runs/cancel \
--data '{ "run_id": <run-id> }'
```

[More Details](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs.html#runs-cancel)

Comment: Yes, but we need successful completion of the job to be logged and seen in the UI.